# Почему не работает конструктор по умолчанию Python

Tags: python

Не могу понять причину почему не работает конструктор и выдает сообщение: "non-default argument follows default argument"

Мой код

```
class Microwave:
"""Микроволновка просто"""

def __init__(self,time=0,power=0,make,model,year):
    self.time =time
    self.power = power
    self.make = make
    self.model = model
    self.year = year
```

Comment: Так прямо в сообщении и написано почему.

Comment: Примерный перевод сообщения об ошибке: "аргументы без значений по-умолчанию (non-default) идут после аргументов со значением по-умолчанию".

Comment: Мой косяк, просто смотрел в примерах  и не думал, что расположении влияет. В пайтоне начал только (в плюсах бы два отдельных конструктора сделал)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Смотрите:

- `make, model, year` -- это позиционные аргументы
- `time=0, power=0` -- именованные аргументы

т.е. аргументы с значением по умолчанию становятся именованными.

А именованные строго **идут после** позиционных

Правильно так:

```
class Microwave:
    """Микроволновка просто"""

    def __init__(self, make, model, year, time=0, power=0):
        self.time =time
        self.power = power
        self.make = make
        self.model = model
        self.year = year
```

---

Именованные хороши тем, что порядок их заполнения в конструкторе не определен, т.е. можно так:

- `Microwave(make, model, year)`
- `Microwave(make, model, year, time=0)`
- `Microwave(make, model, year, power=0)`
- `Microwave(make, model, year, time=0, power=0)`
- `Microwave(make, model, year, power=0, time=0)`

Comment: Не совсем строго. Строго там идёт звездочка `* | *args` сначала, а после неё `только именованные`.